# Socket connection in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning & developing ios application with swift.I have 2 tabs in my app,so I have 2 view controller.I need to connect socket server.But in which file ?

First tab is showing conversations list and second tab is chat interface.User is sending message from second tab.If someone sends a message to this user,I need to show this message in first tab.

I need to connect socket server but in which file ? I mean example: When message arrives to this user i need to save it to database and show user in second tab.Is view controller file good for this case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). It is a fantastic networking library built entirely for Swift and has really picked up in popularity of the past few months. This makes it incredibly easy to call a web service to fetch data.

#### WebSockets

If you actually need to connect to your server using web sockets, then I'd check out [SocketRocket](https://corner.squareup.com/2012/02/socketrocket-websockets.html) built by the fine folks at Square. Here's a link to their project on [Github](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket).

Since you're new to iOS development, I'd suggest a simple architecture where you abstract the network calls out of your view controllers.

#### ChatManager

- Internally manages all networking such as SocketRocket
- Should be a singleton or property on UIApplicationDelegate
- Has public API for sending message
- Sends out notifications when it receives notifications back

---

```
class ChatManager {

    // Add property for socket

    class var sharedInstance: ChatManager {
        struct Singleton { static let instance = ChatManager() }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    init() {
        // Create the socket
    }

    func sendMessage(message: String) {
        // Push the message onto the socket
    }

    // Delegate methods

    func messageReceived(message: String) {
        // Emit the message using NSNotificationCenter
    }
}
```

---

#### View Controller 1

- Subscribes to notifications from ChatManager

---

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Register for NSNotification coming from ChatManager
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

---

#### View Controller 2

- Subscribes to notifications from ChatManager
- Sends new messages to the ChatManager to push through the socket

---

```
class ViewController2 : UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Register for NSNotification coming from ChatManager
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func userAddedNewChatMessage(message: String) {
        ChatManager.sharedInstance.sendMessage(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use socketrocket.But in which file ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: Hi @Okan, I updated the answer to include the file information you're looking for.

Comment: You mean i should connect to socket server in app delegate file right ?

Comment: No, you should create a `ChatManager` class that uses the singleton pattern or is instantiated as a property in the UIApplicationDelegate. Inside the `ChatManager` class, you will create the socket. The `ChatManager` will also be the delegate for the socket to be notified when a new message arrives. Then the `ChatManager` can use NSNotificationCenter to broadcast that message out to any observers, which in your case will be both your View Controllers.

Comment: Can you give a little example ? Just For structure not socket connect mechanism

Comment: Added an example of all three classes. This should be more than enough to you to run with.

Comment: I am creating chatManager instance inside app delegate.Is this a good approach ?

Comment: @cnoon we know you rock with Alamofire and AFNetworking. 
Stay Blessed and Cheers !